# composer removes previous autoloaded files

Tags: php, composer-php

When I execute command the `composer update` it removes previous autoloaded files
if it is not exist more in composer.json file. 
Is there any way to append autoload files by executing command?

composer.json

```
{
"name": "corephp",
"description": "corephp.",
"keywords": ["framework", "corephp"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "App/ClassFiles"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "App/",
        "Model\\": "App/Model/",
        "Controller\\": "App/Controller/",
        "Vendor\\": "vendor"
    },
    "files": [
        "config/constants.php",
        "App/CommonFunction/CommonFunction.php"
    ]
}
}
```

executed command : `composer update` loaded all autoload files.

2nd time executed composer command with below json file and missing some psr-4.

```
{
"name": "corephp",
"description": "corephp.",
"keywords": ["framework", "corephp"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "App/ClassFiles"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Controller\\": "App/Controller/",
        "Vendor\\": "vendor"
    },
    "files": [
        "config/constants.php",
        "App/CommonFunction/CommonFunction.php"
    ]
}
}
```

executed again composer.json. It removes the two autoloaded namespace. Is there any way to append other autoloaded namespaces. I don't want to remove any earlier autoloaded files.

removed namespaces :

```
"App\\": "App/",
"Model\\": "App/Model/",
```

Comment: No body is there to answer ? :(

Comment: Why you need to do that? What's your use case?

Comment: Actually composer.json is deleted. And I don't know which files are previously autoloaded. There are lot of autoloaded files so I cant do it manually.